# Python - Retrieve and use a cookie to download a file

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

Trying to download the following file:

https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD14A2.006/2017.10.24/MYD14A2.A2017297.h19v01.006.2017310142443.hdf

I first need to sign into the following site before doing so:

https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov

After reviewing my browser's web console, I believe it's using a cookie to allow me to download the file.  How can I do this using python?  I find out how to retrieve the cookies:

```
import os, requests

username = 'user'
password = 'pwd'

url = 'https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov'
r = requests.get(url, auth=(username,password))
cookies = r.cookies
```

How can I then use this to download the HDF file?  I've tried the following but always receive 401 error.

```
url2 = "https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD14A2.006/2017.10.24/MYD14A2.A2017297.h19v01.006.2017310142443.hdf"
r2 = requests.get(url2, cookies=r.cookies)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a simple basic authentification :

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url2='https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD14A2.006/2017.10.24/MYD14A2.A2017297.h19v01.006.2017310142443.hdf'
requests.get(url2, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

or read this [example](https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/EL/How+To+Access+Data+With+Python)

Answer (score 2):

To download a file using the Requests library with the browser cookies, you can use the next function:

```
import browser_cookie3
import requests
import shutil
import os 
cj = browser_cookie3.brave()

def download_file(url, root_des_path='./'):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    local_filename = os.path.join(root_des_path, local_filename)
    # r = requests.get(link, cookies=cj)
    with requests.get(url, cookies=cj, stream=True) as r:
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:            
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    return local_filename

a = download_file(link)
```

In this example, cj is the cookies of Brave browser ( you can use ffox or chrome). then, these cj are passed to Requests to download the file.

Note, you need to get "browser_cookie3" library

```
pip install browser-cookie3
```